# nolds module lyap_e function for n-dim systems

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to use the function lyap_e from nolds (https://cschoel.github.io/nolds/nolds.html#lyapunov-exponent-eckmann-et-al) to compute the lyapunov exponents of a n-dim system.
for example, I start with a 2d system where I store the values in
`combined_data = np.zeros((reps, 2))`, reps being the number of time steps.
When I call `lyap_exp = lyap_e(combined_data, emb_dim=10, matrix_dim=4)` I get an error ("The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous...").
It seems that the problem is with how I provide the 2d dataset (or does it even accept 2d dataset?, from the documentation it would appear so).
Does anyone know how to solve this?

I've tried building the array in different ways but it always gives the same error

Comment: Please share the full traceback where the error happens and if possible how you exactly define the variables that appear as a cause in the traceback.